# change wordpress site slug

Tags: wordpress, parent-child, slug

I need to adding something in my child functions.php to change slug from "campaigns" to something else.
Right now it depends on

```
define( 'EDD_SLUG', apply_filters( 'atcf_edd_slug', 'campaigns' ) );
```

from a plugin. I can't edit that plugin (should be update often) and I should resolve it in child theme

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function replace NEWSLUG with whatever you want that slug to be.

```
function wpse_update_slug( $slug ) {
    return 'NEWSLUG';
}
add_filter( 'atcf_edd_slug', 'wpse_update_slug' );
```

Comment: What happens when you add this? There was a typo by the way so please correct if you did a direct copy and paste. It's on the last line. I've updated my question

Comment: Are you sure you have placed this in your child themes functions.php and the child theme is active? Can you add the following line of code to be sure (put this in header.php). `<?php echo '<pre>' . EDD_SLUG . '</pre>'; ?>` Paste the output here.

Comment: no, luck, output "campaigns". maybe I should told you that "campaigns" are custom post type.

Comment: And you're sure that you fixed the typo in the code? This code changes the output of EDD_SLUG. There are a very limited number of circumstances where this wouldn't work.

Comment: Which plugin is this in? Easy digital downloads doesn't define this constant.https://easydigitaldownloads.com/docs/edd_slug/

Comment: It's crowdfunding by astoundify. A plugin that requires Easy digital downloads but re-defines edd_slug in "campaigns"